# How to display Play framework 'log' on IDEA console

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I want to display Play framework 'log' on idea console.

I follow the instructions in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/IDE remote debug settings, but the log is not output on idea console.

It just displayed **'Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost: 9999', transport: 'socket'**

How to display it? such as "[INFO] blah blah, [DEBUG] blah blah"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to start play from inside of IDEA through the IDEA Play Plugin to get the output inside of IDEA.

Add a new Run/Debug configuration and select "Play 2 App" and then start that from inside of IDEA.2